# Algorithm to determine the closest date to some date input

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a Python program that uses historical data coming from a database and allows the user to select the dates input. However not all the possible dates are available into the database, since these are financial data: in other words, if the user will insert "02/03/2014" (which is Sunday) he won't find any record in the database because the stock exchange was closed.

This causes SQL problems cause when the record is not found, the SQL statement fails and the user needs to adjust the date until the moment he finds an existing record. To avoid this I would like to build an algorithm which is able to change the date inputs itself choosing the closest to the originary input. For example, if the user inserts "02/03/2014", the closest would be 03/03/2014".

I have thought about something like this, where the table *MyData* is containing date values only (I'm still in process of working on the proper syntaxis but it's just to show the idea):

```
con = lite.connect('C:/.../MyDatabase.db')
cur = con.cursor() 
cur.execute('SELECT * from MyDates')
rowsD= cur.fetchall()
data = []
for row in rowsD:
    data.append(rowsD[row])           

>>>data
['01/01/2010', '02/01/2010', .... '31/12/2013']

inputDate = '07/01/2010'
differences = []
for i in range(0, len(data)):
    differences.append(abs(data[i] - inputDate))
```

After that, I was thinking about:

- getting the minimum value from the vector differences: `mV = min(differences)`
- getting the corresponding date value into the list `data`

Howwever, this cost me two things in terms of memory:

1. I need to load all the database, which is huge;
2. I have to iterate many times (once to build the list data, then the list of differences etc.)

Does anyone have a better idea to build this, or knows a different approach to the problem?

Comment: If you know the distribution of the dates, fetch a window of possible dates within (say) the maximum gap anywhere in the data.  If no two adjacent dates are further apart than 12 hours, you could double that (just to be a little bit safer in case there is a new record), and search +/- 24 hours, then further process the results from that query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query the database on the dates that are smaller than the input date and take the maximum of these. This will give you the closest date before.

Symmetrically, you can query the minimum of the larger dates to get the closest date after. And keep the preferred of the two.

These should be efficient queries.

```
SELECT MAX(Date)
FROM MyDates
WHERE Date <= InputDate;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try getting a record with the maximum date smaller then the given one from database directly (this can be done with SQL). If you put an index in your database on date then this can be done in O(log(n)). That's of course not really the same as "being closest" but if you combine it with "the minimum date bigger then the given one" you will achieve it.

Also if you know more or less the distribution of your data, for example that in each 7 consecutive days you have some data, then you can restrict to a smaller range of data like [-3 days, +3 days].

Combining both of these solutions should give you quite nice performance.